# In block wedge system why horizontal component of normal doesn't affect the momentum of the system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

Diag. For ques:

[image]

In that L shaped wedge of 4kg a block of 1kg is released from top... We give the reason of not conserving momentum in $y$ direction that a vertical component of normal due to the curved edge surface is constantly changing the gravitational force... But my query was that the normal at that curved surface of the wedge has some horizontal component too.. So why don't we consider that force and say that the momentum is not conserved in $x$.... And if anyone gives the reason that that horizontal component is been balanced by the block then is not the vertical component not too being balanced by the block.

Comment: Is this wedge fixed in place or able to slide on a friction-less horizontal surface?

Answer (score 0):

If we consider Block + Wedge as a system then the Normal here you are talking about is internal force so it's already out of context here ; The reason you are giving to not conserve the momentum in y direction is also flawed, it is actually because of The normal reaction by the surface on the wedge

See if you only consider block as system then in many questions u will certainly observe that the momentum of block has changed while travelling downward !!

Hope it helped u :)

Comment: Thnx a lot Yash... That helped me a lot :)